# How to make space between div's static and space left/right depend on browsers width?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make space between div's static and space left/right depend on browsers width?
The div's should be centred. The space left/right should be equal and depend on browser width.
Amount of columns should be depends on browser width (like it is now).

The height of div's `.box` are different. `<br>` is used only for showing the different height of some div's.

```css
.under {
width:70%;
margin:auto;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:40px;
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid green;
overflow:auto; 
justify-content: center;
position:relative;
column-count: 5;
}

.box {
text-align:center;
width:314px;
padding:10px;
margin:10px;
display:inline-block;
box-shadow: 0px 5px #1c1c1c, 0px  -2px #1c1c1c;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
background-color: #363636;
border: 0px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2450px) {
 .under {
  column-count: 4;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1900px) {
 .under {
  column-count: 3;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
 .under {
  column-count: 2;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 .under {
  column-count: 1;
 }
}

body {
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
background-color:#262626!important;
color:#ddd!important;
font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="under">
  <div class="box">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 2<br><br><br>end</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 3</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 4</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 5<br><br/>end</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 6</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 7</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 8</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 9<br><br><br><br>end</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 10</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 11</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use basic flex box, if you make it flex box then this will happen automatically with flex wrap and content set to fix width.

```css
.under {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 314px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #363636;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="under">
  <div class="box" style="height:50px;">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="box" style="height:90px;">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 3</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 4</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 5</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 6</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 7</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 8</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 9</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 10</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 11</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **.box** should be allways 314px. Space between boxes should be allways static. In you example the space between is depend on browser width.

Comment: Have tryied flexbox before. The problem is with space between rows (different div's height) and centering lowest row. See screen: https://i.imgur.com/1LeAQ29.png

Comment: You just need to set it to align the boxes differently https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/